# UITabBar unresponsive on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have an existing iPhone project that has been tested, submitted, and approved, compiled with the 3.1.3 SDK. I've taken this project and converted it to a universal iPad/iPhone app, following Apple's instructions (i.e. letting Xcode do its magic).

This app has a `UITabBarController` as its root view controller, built inside a XIB. When run on the 4.0 iPhone simulator, it works fine. When running on the 3.2 iPad Simulator or the device itself, it has one major flaw: the UITabBar is unresponsive. I can't change any of the tabs; taps on any part of the UITabBar don't seem to ever get registered. I can tap on the view of the current tab's view controller no problem.

Since the `UITabBarController` is created inside a XIB, I also create its tabs (view controllers) inside the XIB as well. If I add or subtract tabs, that seems to update the UITabBar fine. But still, none of the actual tabs are tappable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the automagic option that Apple put into Xcode to convert iPhone projects to universal iPhone/iPad projects didn't set the "Full Screen at Launch" flag for my `UIWindow` instance in my MainWindow-iPad.xib, which meant that all touches outside of its hard-coded 320x480 frame were not getting sent to my application.