# upgrade to universal app - size of mainWindow-iPad is 320x480

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I have the following problem.
I have an iPhone app and want to upgrade to universal
When I do this, I get the expected MainWindow-iPad.xib.
But the size of the window is hardcoded to 320x480.
Also, there is no view in the window.
I red, this should be automatically iPad-sized, so I am assuming I am doing something wrong.
What exactly am I missing ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dimensions of a `UIWindow` object are hard-coded to the size of the iPhone screen. This confused me, too, until I realized there was an option to resize it: select the `UIWindow` object in the .xib in Interface Builder... in the Attributes pane, make sure the "Full Screen at Launch" checkbox is checked.

As St3fan says you'll probably want to have a specific main window .xib for your iPad build.

See my answer at:

[UITabBar unresponsive on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295000/uitabbar-unresponsive-on-ipad)

Comment: now im confused :-)
I have this MainWindow-iPad.xib.
Fullscreen on launch is enabled - but it still is 320x480. So a subview I add cant be bigger, right ?

And btw: in the MainWindow-iPad.xib there also is my original viewcontroller. So when I launch the iPad emulator, it shows me basically the iPhone version in the top left corner of the iPad Simulator. ( at least it is still fully functional :-)
Sorry if I dind't get the point :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got this. I fixed it by deleting the automatically created ipad xib, then opening the original xib in interface builder and choosing convert to iPad from the menu. Then ni saved it with the -iPad name and added it to the corredt target.

Comment: hey, that did it - Thanks a lot.
But one more thing >
I have this MainWindow/iPad.xib and in mz plist is the main nib file base name iPad set to its name.
But when I launch in iPad emulator, it still seems to load the iphone version into the upper left corner.

Comment: ok. I fixed it by creating a iPad Version of the ViewController with IB, then saved the classes, saved the nib and then build up the nib content of MainWindow-iPad.xib from scratch. 
thanks for all the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably also need to create a `MainWindow-iphone.xib` and `MainWindow-ipad.xib`.

Comment: hmm. ok. xcode created the MainWindow-iPad.xib for me, right ?
and I have the original mainWindow.xib.
is that ok so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a GLES application - using EAGLView, in a manner similar to all of the samples, but wanting to support iphone3,iphone4,and ipad.

in my context creation from [EAGLView initWithCoder], I was forcing the eaglLayer's rect to match the main screen, which worked for iphone and iphone4 (i.e. gave me a 320x480 or 640x960 gl surface), but for ipad, this gave me a 768x1024 surface which was cropped on present to 640x960.
As it turns out, The "Full Screen at Launch" option seems to be applied AFTER the view's (EAGLView, in my case) initWithCoder.

My solution was to do nothing in the [EAGLView initWithCoder], and only actually initialize my view after the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called, in the layoutSubviews call.

HTH,
forks