# unresponsive TabBar in universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application developed on the iphone. I have recently started making it universal, but when i run it on the ipad simulator the TabBar on my ipad simulator is completely unresponsive. How do i fix this? I read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295000/uitabbar-unresponsive-on-ipad), but the answer did not give any solutions.

Comment: There is very little information here. Let us know what steps you've taken till now in making it universal and which is the related question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the check box. It was located under "window" in my inspector.